# Is it possible to repeatedly trigger sixtieth hour events?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When exploring the wasteland, there are special events that trigger at or around 60 hours of exploration. Is it possible to recall someone who has been exploring 61 hours and triggered the event and then tell them to resume exploring once they've walked an hour home to trigger the event again? The hour walk home will have set their exploration timer to 59 hours, so will they find the event the second time their timer is at 60 hours?

Comment: Interesting, what do these events consist of? Not sure that I have seen one

Comment: I believe its the National Guard Depot. That one is the one guaranteed as a legendary weapon. Row 147 in this spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/edit#gid=1591448540

Comment: This should be fairly easy to test, as there are also [wasteland events](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/edit#gid=1591448540) that happen at other event increments; 0:30, for instance. So one could feasibly send a dweller exploring for 31 minutes, *[have them return for 1 minute, explore again for 2 minutes]* etc, to repeatedly trigger the 30 minute event. If it happens, then it's a solid bet that the 60 hour event will repeat as well. The challenge is surviving that long in the first place. ;)

Comment: Alternately, you could send your explorer out, set your system clock to 2.5 days in the future, and check on him. That ought to be a pretty quick test as well.

Comment: I've got somebody at 56 hours so I will update this soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer for 1.2+

With the latest update, recalling a dweller from the wasteland does NOT count down your explore timer.  If you were at 60 hour, recall him for 8 hours, and then set him to explore again, he will resume exploring at the initial time.

This also means if you then recall again, his return trip is reset and you have to start again at `Explore Time / 2`.

Answer (score 6):

I can't certify this for all major events, but for the 60th hour National Guard Depot, I can confirm that you must return to the vault to trigger it again. I ran my dweller up to 61 hours (measly 125 xp from the National Guard, no weapon), then back to 58, and upon hitting 60 again it triggered a "standard" event of finding something in the wasteland. Therefore I conclude that you must return to the vault in order to be able to trigger the National Guard again.

Comment: If anyone has any other information to add feel free to add it as an answer, I don't want to accept mine immediately as there are plenty other events that could still trigger repeatedly that I haven't tested. the googledocs spreadsheet in the comments on the question has more details there.

Comment: You mention "for all major events." Are there other major events when wandering in the wasteland?

Comment: In the spreadsheet I linked above it lists events that happen at specific times. National Guard is the only one that rewards a legendary item, but there are others that reward rares or various amounts of caps and XP. Check tab 7 - Wastes and scroll down to around row 125 for the list

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. If you recall a dweller from say 61 to 58 hours, and then set him to explore again, nothing will happen until he's at 61+

Comment: Do you know if this has changed recently, and can you identify when it changed if so? When I did the same experiment he had a standard event pop up at 60 hours, hence my answer above. If you can add more details showing that it's changed, I'd be happy to change the accepted answer to yours. As it stands, you're not adding much new info. Thanks!